# RTOS with dynamic update of a thread

Tags: arm, embedded, rtos

I'm looking for an embedded RTOS that supports the dynamic upgrade/replacement of a thread. This should be used to allow the user to perform a network based upgrade of the running application. This should basically work like a bootloader, but without replacing the entire application.

My target architecture is an ARM Cortex-M4 processor, so I am looking for a deeply embedded RTOS such as FreeRTOS.

Comment: It is too broad for SO. BTW I guess you don't need an RTOS to do what you are asking for, but a simple bootloader with a network layer.

Comment: most "deeply embedded" RTOS deploy the application as one single monolithic block. You would be better off with embedded  Linux.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the traditional bootloader and firmware update procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure that I get your question right, but for me it seems that dynamic modules support is what you need. Using this feature you could implement partial-firmware OTA update. If so, you could look at [NuttX](http://nuttx.org/), [RIOT OS](https://www.riot-os.org/) or [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/). It looks like that they all support the requested feature. If you are asking about [live update](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:liveupdate), than you probably should consider [Minix 3](http://www.minix3.org/), but I'am not sure that it fits your target device.